# Feature matrix as the kronecker product of two feature matrices. How to build an alternative?

Tags: regression, feature-selection

I have two feature matrices $\textbf{X}$ and $\textbf{Y}$ which I encoded through one-hot encoding the rows of two feature matrices $\textbf{X'}$ and $\textbf{Y'}$. Thus, they are sparse with a few 1's in each row. I'm trying to solve the following equation

$(\textbf{X}\otimes\textbf{Y})\textbf{w}=\textbf{z}$

Using the matrix $(\textbf{X}\otimes\textbf{Y})$ I get 0 error in training. However, this matrix is very large. Is there any other matrix I can use as a basis?

I have tried pairwise multiplication and concatenation of the rows in $\textbf{X},\textbf{Y}$, i.e., $\phi(\textbf{x}_i,\textbf{y}_j)=[\textbf{x}_i,\textbf{y}_j]$ but it doesn't work very well. 
Is there any function $\phi(\textbf{X},\textbf{Y})$  that gives me a matrix with a small number of columns I can use to approximate the space spanned by $\textbf{X}\otimes\textbf{Y}$? I would like to avoid using methods such as PCA or kernels.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @StatsStudent The question seems to be "is there any other matrix I can use as a basis?"

Comment: @PeterFlom, the question is now clear after some updating from the OP.  It wasn't clear previously.  Now it looks good!

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to mention that I edited the question